# Calculate high-order roots by hand

Tags: roots

Say you were asked to calculate a high-order root by hand. For example, the 13th root of 230,120,000 to 4 significant digits.

How would you do it? Would you do a manual Newton-Raphson iteration? Or perhaps a more crude sequence of repeated guessing? Would you manually calculate a Taylor series? What would be the fastest approach?

Answer (score 2):

One could use logarithms for such a problem .

For example ,lets take ,as you said, 230120000$^{1/13}$

Set Z = 230120000$^{1/13}$

log$_{10}$(Z) = $\frac{1}{13}$.log$_{10}$(230120000)

=$\frac{1}{13}$.(5+3.361954)

=$\frac{8.3619954}{13}$

log$_{10}$(Z)=0.64322723076

Z = 10$^{0.64322723076}$

Z = 4.397717

Therefore the 13$^{th}$ root of 230,120,000 is 4.397717

Virtually any root is calculable along with many other calculations  if one has a log book handy.

$Note$ : I'm using base 10 but you can use any base with respect to the number whose root you want to find .

Comment: OP asks for fastest approach.

Comment: well this would be considerably faster than just guessing the root or using a Taylor expansion. Also I've drawn it out a bit here . If done properly wouldn't take more than a minute or faster .

Comment: Well, I asked for calculation by hand. Looking up a logarithm is not calculation by hand.

Comment: Fair point, still i find it easier than the rest.